# How to create release from tag that will show on the releases list?

Tags: git, github, github-release

I added some tags through git (command-line) and tried to create a release that will show under "releases", but unfortunately every time I create a release it will always show up in "tags".

I used the command-line to create 3 tags:
v0.1 (from an old commit)
v0.1.1 (from another old commit)
v0.1.2 (from another old commit)
Every time I create a release and add an existing tag the release won't show up.

Comment: How do you create a release? AFAIK this has to be done via GitHub's web UI (or API). Git itself does not support "releases" in a repository.

Comment: Yeah, git knows no such thing as a release. This is a github concept.

Comment: Well in GitHub you have to connect a tag for each release, so what I'm trying to do is connect a release to an old tag, and make it show up in the releases list.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in one of the comments, git doesn't have a concept of releases, just tags. You can name your tags like release_xyz if you want.